# How to post dynamic JSON string using JQuery's get function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

What I want to achieve is passing a json string as Get method to server with jquery. The content that is sent back is html type. I use the function .get("url", myJson, callback) to accomplish this.

To make my json string I verify some checkbox and textbox to get their content and add their id/value on the json string if needed.

I used an array that I added my value like:

```
var array = new Array();
array.push("att_id:"+value);
```

and then used this to make the json:

```
var jsonString = "{" + array.join(",") + "}";
```

But when I make a request to the server like this:

```
$.get(
    "localhost/something",
    $jsonString,
    function(data){
        $("#something").html(data);
});
```

It doesn't work cause it pass the jsonString as the arraykey and a null value.
So I'm looking for a method to achieve this.

Comment: big confusion between php and js here ;)

Comment: I'm new with json and I thought a string would be convert to json if the syntax matches

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (quick fix):

```
$.get(
    "localhost/something",
    {theData:array},
    function(data){
        $("#something").html(data);
    }
);
```

Or, more in the spirit of jQuery (since you really want to pass a Javascript key-value map (i.e. an object) rather than a pre-JSON-ified string):

```
var $dataObj = {};
$dataObj["att_id"]=value;

// and then
$.get(
    "localhost/something",
    $dataObj,
    function(data){
        $("#something").html(data);
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks I didn't know this syntax... should do exactly what I want!

Comment: It migth sounds strange... but what does the $dataObj = {} does exactly? Declaring an empty object?

Comment: Yep, it's just a handy shortcut for creating a new empty object. Similarly, you can create a new empty array by doing: var arr = [];

Answer (score 0):

You just build the data with an object literal:

```
var data = {foo: "bar", att_id: value};
$.get(
    "localhost/something",
    data,
    function(data){
        $("#something").html(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Create the json string as below.

```
var data = {};
//Add as many key/values as you want
data["att_id"] = value;


$.get(
    "localhost/something",
    data,
    function(data){
        $("#something").html(data);
    }
);
```

Comment: Um... that's not really a string. The code will work of course, but the variable naming is quite misleading

Comment: @JensRoland - Thought of going with OP defined variable to make it easy to understand, anyways rename it :)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [JSON2](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) polyfill for JSON.stringify, and get rid of the array.

```
var data= {};
data["att_id"]=value;

$.get(
    "localhost/something",
    JSON.stringify(data),
    function(result){
        $("#something").html(result);
    }
);
```